# Concatenating Columns into Dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Okay I currently have a column of dates whose dtype is object.

Output is as follows:

```
720344    31/12/2016
720345    31/12/2016
720346    31/12/2016
720347    31/12/2016
720348    31/12/2016
```

Then I have a column of time whose dtype is timedelta64[ns] and it's output looks like

```
10       00:15:04
11       00:12:20
12       00:14:37
13       00:18:42
```

I've read a couple of threads and it seems I need to use the pd.to_datetime function somehow.

I've tried:

```
pd.to_datetime(dfdate['INCIDENT_DATE'] + " " + dfdate['DispatchTime'])
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<U11') and dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

I guess it doesn't like the object + timedelta command.

Then I tried to convert the time to a str with this:

```
pd.to_datetime(dfdate['INCIDENT_DATE'] + " " + str(dfdate['DispatchTime']))
```

But now i get a different error:

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You wanna go from `31/12/2016` and `00:15:0` to a concatenated datetime obj like `31/12/2016 00:15:04` ?

Comment: Yes Raf, should've clarified that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is necessary convert column `INCIDENT_DATE` to `datetime`s by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then add `DispatchTime` column, because `timedelta`s:

```
print (dfdate.dtypes)
INCIDENT_DATE             object
DispatchTime     timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

dfdate['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfdate['INCIDENT_DATE']) + dfdate['DispatchTime']
print (dfdate)
       INCIDENT_DATE DispatchTime                date
720344    31/12/2016     00:15:04 2016-12-31 00:15:04
720345    31/12/2016     00:12:20 2016-12-31 00:12:20
720346    31/12/2016     00:14:37 2016-12-31 00:14:37
720347    31/12/2016     00:18:42 2016-12-31 00:18:42
```